# Error with ResultSet.next()

Tags: jsp, resultset

I don't know why I receive a SQLException in my code:

```
int i=0;
while(result.next()) {
      book[i]=BookService.getBook(database, result.getInt("id_number"));
      i++;
}
```

In particulary, the first time the loop is executed but the second time I receive an error...I think it's a problem of the cursor...how can I fix it?

```
Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

root cause

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: services.databaseservice.exception.ResultSetDBException: General Error: Error in createArrayBook: CartManagement
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:912)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:841)
    org.apache.jsp.cart_jsp._jspService(cart_jsp.java:235)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

root cause

```
services.databaseservice.exception.ResultSetDBException: General Error: Error in createArrayBook: CartManagement
    bflows.CartManagement.createArrayBook(CartManagement.java:98)
    org.apache.jsp.cart_jsp._jspService(cart_jsp.java:105)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

Comment: what particularly error do you get?

Comment: It's always good form to use `resultSet.hasNext()` in a predicate check and run any operations `next()` or otherwise based on its success.

Comment: @S.R.I There is no `hasNext()` method on [java.sql.ResultSet](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html).

Comment: @Raphaël yeah, I realised it after I posted this comment. :(

Comment: OP, in any case, your error is much below the stack trace you posted. Please post the complete stack trace whenever you can

Comment: I this this is what S.R.I intended: http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()

Comment: @MichaelFreake - that's what I had in mind but got distracted :)

Comment: OP, even as your stacktrace is still not complete or you have posted very little code. I can hazard a guess where you went wrong. If `next()` failed the check, the ResultSet cursor would be positioned after the /last/ record. So, you could do something like: `if(!resultSet.isLast() && resultSet.next()) { /* go on, do something here */ }`

Comment: That is, unless you haven't closed the resultset.

Comment: The problem is that after I call book[i]=BookService.getBook(database, result.getInt("id_number")); every operation on result retrieves an error...

Comment: are you sure error is from result?

Comment: It's really hard to find the real problem with the provided code. Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) with your current code to get the real error.